# "Getting Started with Lightroom Mobile" popup disappears before I can click on it!

Tags: lightroom, file-management, lightroom-5

I don't know what it's called, but it's the window at the upper left of the LR window that comes up when you click on "getting started with lightroom mobile" or if you've already signed in, "Your name here"
[image]

So When I click on the text under the first arrow, the window appears, but only for moment before fading away as though I'd clicked on something else. Has anyone else experienced this? Any idea how to stop it from disappearing?

Comment: Change the identity plate to something that isn't an advertisement. First thing I did with LR5.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can get that effect is by having the Module Picker strip  (the strip at the top that lets you pick Library - Develop - Map, etc.) set to disappear automatically, as the Lightroom Mobile selector is within that.

It should work properly if your cursor stays within that area, but if it moves out, the entire module picker strip will disappear to make space.

You could click on the arrow that pins the strip open while you log in or press F5, then hide it again.

Hope that helps

Comment: I tried that, but it happens whether the module bar is hidden or shown.  And moving my mouse doesn't affect it either, if I keep it right over the triangle twirl down, it still disappears.